# Export DataGrid View To Excel/PDF

Tags: wpf, excel, datagrid, export, wpfdatagrid

I would like to implement a feature to export a datagrid view with grouped items, like this:

[image]

I'd like to create an Excel spreadsheet (and possibly PDF) that also maintains the groupings appear.

Have any of you ever done something like that or know tell me a way forward? Thanks.

P.S. For Excel document generation thought to use the EPPlus library.

Comment: What's wrong with using the built in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` dlls? There are plenty of tutorials online if you search for that name.

Comment: The main problem is not the choice of Excel library, but how read each row of datagrid with its group. In order to define an Excel spreadsheet equals to datagrid view.

Comment: On this site, *you* need to make an effort before you can receive help. No one will do your work for you, so I suggest that you pick a library and attempt to achieve this your self. If you get stuck, then return and edit your question, showing your attempted code.

Comment: Ok maybe I got a little bit away, actually I just wanted an indication of how run scan the DataGrid rows to be able to read the tree elements according to the groups displayed. In any case I'm trying to do this by analyzing the properties "Groups" list "Items" associated with the DataGrid.